# Windows 10 places login screen on my closed laptop lid at boot time

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have an HP zBook 15 mobile workstation laptop running Windows 10 1709. The laptop is normally docked, with 3 external monitors. Since the 1703 update or thereabouts, when I boot up the laptop using the power button on the docking station, I will see the BIOS screen and the "starting Windows" messages on an external monitor, and then all 3 external monitors will go blank. It always takes me a moment to realize the login screen is on the laptop monitor, which is closed. I need to open and then close the laptop screen in order for the login screen to be correctly displayed on my primary monitor.

This was not an issue in Windows 7. In the Settings app, my 3 monitors are the only ones recognized (not the laptop screen, since it's closed). I've Googled about this problem on and off for the last several months but it doesn't seem to be a known issue.

I recently installed all available Windows updates as well as BIOS update and some firmware updates from HP, but the problem persists. Is there any way of getting Windows 10 to realize the laptop lid is closed when it first boots up?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your laptop lid to get a dual monitor setup
2. Make sure that the two monitors are not mirrored but extended
3. Select the external monitor and check the checkbox saying "Make this my main display"
4. At next reboot, the login screen should show up on your external monitor

Comment: Thanks but I already have one of the external monitors set as the main display. The problem seems to happen if I shut down the laptop when it's off of its dock. When I place it back on the dock (closed) and boot up, the POST screen, Bitlocker etc goes on an external monitor but then the Windows login screen goes on the closed laptop lid. I have to open and close the lid to get it on an external display.

Comment: This helped me out. I had the same problem as OP but the fix was actually to open the lid of the laptop first, then choose the external monitor as primary. After that, the laptop lid can be closed and the login screen will use the external monitor as the primary.